# Hibernate does not see inserted in sql script data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

Project worked on Spring Boot (v. 2.0.5), Hibernate (v. 5.2.17), Ehcache, Flyway, Solr.
I have an ConceptEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "concept", schema = "common")
public class ConceptEntity extends AbstractAuditableEntity {
    private long id;
    private Long organizationId;
    private String comment;
    private String systemName;
    private Long conceptTypeId;
    private ConceptTypeEntity conceptType;

    List<ConceptTermEntity> conceptTerm;
    List<ConceptDefinitionEntity> conceptDefinition;
    List<ConceptAbbreviationEntity> conceptAbbreviation;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator( name="seq", sequenceName="common.common_generic_seq", allocationSize=1 )
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "organization_id")
    public Long getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }
    ...
}
```

My repository component:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Transactional
public class OntologyDAOImpl implements OntologyDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    ...
    @Override
    public ConceptEntity findConceptByTypeAndSystemName(String conceptTypeSettings, String category) {
        return em.createNamedQuery(ConceptEntity.FIND_BY_TYPE_NAME_AND_NAME, ConceptEntity.class)
            .setParameter("conceptTypeSystemName", conceptTypeSettings)
            .setParameter("systemName", category)
            .getSingleResult();//NoResultException
    }
    ...
}
```

And persistence.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MDM_ADMIN</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.isolation">1</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
      <mapping class="mdm.ontology.entity.ConceptEntity"/>
      <mapping class="rcg.mdm.admin.entity.EmailEntity"/>
      ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I inserted 2 rows in common.concept with help SQL editor.
Then I started the Application, I see what EntityManager didn't find these rows.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM common.concept = 103696
em.find(ConceptEntity.class, 103696l) = null (<=103694 hibernate returns)
```

My application.yml:

```
...
spring:
  cache.jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache3.xml


  jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc:
    lob.non_contextual_creation: true
    naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

  datasource:
  ...
```

What should I do to get the Hibernate back to me the entries created in the SQL script? I don't have @Cache anywere in project.

Comment: `em.find(ConceptEntity.class, 103696l)` the id value have to be 103696 not 1036961

Comment: It's not a one, it's a L - long.

Comment: what do you get for `select * from common.concept where id=103696`

Comment: The record as it presented in table. All data what I write in my Insert query in Sql editor.